# как правильно переопределить метод SetValueAt()?

Tags: java

при переопределении данного метода выдается ошибка:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

Как ее убрать?

Фрагмент кода программы :

```
public class AbstrTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {


 HashMap<Integer, Smartphone> hashMap;
 public static int key = 0;
 private File fin;
 private Scanner fileScanner;

 public AbstrTableModel(){
    AbstrTableModel.key = 0;
    hashMap = new  HashMap<Integer, Smartphone>();
}

//-------------------------------------

 @Override
 public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
  switch(columnIndex){
    case 1:
        hashMap.get(rowIndex).setModel() = (String)value;
        return;
    case 2:
        hashMap.get(rowIndex).setRazmer() = (Double)value;
        return;
    case 3:
        hashMap.get(rowIndex).setTip_displeya()= (String)value;
        return;
    case 4:
        hashMap.get(rowIndex).setVmFlash()= (Integer)value;
        return;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка значит - "в левой части оператора присваивания должна быть переменная".

Вы не можете использовать конструкцию `hashMap.get(rowIndex).setModel()` в левой части операции присваивания.
Если `setModel()` -метод-сеттер, то он и должен устанавливать какое то значение через свой аргумент.

Answer (score 4):

Ругается на строки

> hashMap.get(rowIndex).setModel() = (String)value;

Выражение слева должно быть переменной.

Попробуйте так

> hashMap.get(rowIndex).setModel( (String)value) ;